# What happen with my private room when my reputation goes less than 1000?

Tags: discussion, reputation, chat

I am just wondering. What will happen with my private room when my reputation goes less than 1000. Supposed I have created a private room and my reputation is 1100 then I give bounty of 200. So,  what happen with my private room. Does it become public or inaccessible?

Comment: who said that? I dont think it will have any effect on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, In that case, room will still be in private mode. In that case you can not change room from private to public or from public to private.

Meaning, If you have atleast 1K reputation then you only you get access to the "access tag"

> [image]

Note: Any moderator or developer can talk freely even if you have chat room with gallery mode.

Answer (score 8):

You haven't created a private room, only moderators can do that.

You have likely created a gallery room that only allows specific users to talk. The room owners and the users with write access will stay the same after you lose your reputation, you simply won't be able to create another gallery chat room.